# How to create a raw socket with ZeroMQ in Java?

Tags: zeromq, jeromq

I'm trying to port the ZeroMq [Hello World](https://gist.github.com/hintjens/5480625) Http server to Java from C. In this code snippet, the `router` socket is set to read raw data, but I can't figure out how to do this in Java...

```
zsocket_set_router_raw (router, 1);
```

Based on the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#-MQ-is-Not-a-Neutral-Carrier), a socket type `ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW` exists, so I thought this would work in Java...

```
ZMQ.Socket router = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER_RAW);
```

...but doesn't, in fact, I can't find any constant for this type in the Java [bindings](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/tree/master/src/main/java/org/zeromq). And I can't find a suitable static method either in Socket. I'm suspect I'm missing something under my nose here; it's frustrating because this is a small API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my findings, this is not supported in Java at this time: https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/60